# Managing blocks in a responsive theme

Tags: blocks, theming

I'm just starting a responsive theme based on Omega, concentrating on the mobile layout at first.

There are certain blocks that will probably be deemed too 'heavy' to include on the mobile layout, and other blocks that will need to be introduced specifically for that layout (watered-down menus, toned-down user-bar etc).

I could easily hide the unwanted blocks on the mobile layout with CSS, and include the mobile-specific blocks on the default layout and hide those (so they're only shown for mobile), but that seems like quite a backwards way of thinking about it. If the blocks aren't shown, the extra overhead they incur would really be unacceptable (especially considering the number of extra db queries that the content in hidden blocks would add).

I'm thinking there must be a nice clean way to intercept the block decision-making process early on in the page build, and exclude/include blocks based on some os-detection, but I'm drawing a blank on how that might be possible.

I'm also going to throw in the fact that Varnish is running in front of this site, which should make things more fun :)

Are there modules/known strategies out there that can help with this?

I should add that using the Context module isn't an option as the site is already fully-fledged, and moving it into Context would be a massive undertaking at this point.

Comment: I would without question have used Panels and a relevant user-agent access plugin. Context could probably do the same, but as you already said, that's not an option. There's of course the horrible possibility of eval:ing the block visibility, but... On the other hand, with Varnish up front, the extra db-queries these block perform, might not be much of an issue?

Comment: @Letharion Yeah that's the thinking, let Varnish remove the strain. The site has a few hundred thousand active users though, and Varnish only gets involved for anonymous traffic. We'll be playing with ESI fairly soon but even then I can think of problems...from an SEO point of view the extra markup/menus would be heavy and potentially confusing, not to mention the extra (unnecessary) weight on pages for mobile users. It's a tough one!

Comment: Perhaps add a more intelligent block handler (Panels/Context/other) to the heaviest pages, so you can get some gain from it without needing to redo the entire site?

Comment: @Letharion It looks like that would be the way to go - swapping out the heavy pages one-by-one with something a bit more intelligent than what's there now. If you want to summarise that into an answer it'll definitely be considered, it's a good idea

Comment: That extra fun of adding Varnish seems to change the game totally:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40473/drupal-shows-mobile-theme-on-desktop

Comment: @user1007846 thanks, I've been slowly realising that this is a bit of a stupid question anyway for exactly that reason

Comment: I disagree that it makes the question stupid, or a total game changer. Varnish can be configured to handle the problem nicely, it just won't know how with an out of the box configuration.

Comment: @Clive : there's an old saying: "There is no such thing as a stupid question, only a stupid answer!" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> intercept the block decision-making process early on in the page build, and exclude/include blocks based on some os-detection
>
> Varnish is running in front of this site

As noted in the comments already, this requires you to configure varnish to *not* cache only on the request URL, but also vary on the user-agent. There is a relevant example in the varnish wiki, [VCLExampleNormalizeUserAgent](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleNormalizeUserAgent).

Once the request actually *does* hit the site, you need to determine which blocks to show and not to show. I would consider it no less than a disaster to do this with [eval](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args), so the most common options left then are [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) and [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

With the site already built. redoing all pages/block placement with either module is probably not an option, but with a profiler, and applying [80-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle), it could be possible to make significant performance gains by redoing specific pages only.

Comment: That's really really interesting thanks. The site in question is on Pantheon so I don't think configuring Varnish is an option, but this has turned into a more general 'how would one do this theoretically' type question now so this is very helpful

Comment: Pantheon allows you setup STYXKEY cookies (towards the end of http://helpdesk.getpantheon.com/customer/portal/articles/425726 ) , and they allow you to segment what Varnish caches/serves for anon users.

Answer (score 10):

I can't go into a *lot* of details, as I've not used either module for ages (I build all my sites with Context from the word go and I've not picked up responsive on something I haven't built for a while, so I've not had this problem before), but I think you should be able to put something together with Mobile Tools and Spaces.

**[Spaces](http://www.drupal.org/project/spaces)**

> Spaces is an API module intended to make configuration options generally avaliable only at the sitewide level to be configurable and overridden by individual "spaces" on a Drupal site. It has been described as:
>
> - A way to make one Drupal site act like several sites
> - A way to provide much more configurable, full-feature Organic Groups or user homepages
> - A generalized API for contextual configuration

**[Mobile Tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools)**

> The Mobile Tools module provides Drupal developers with some tools to
>   assist in making adjustments to your site based on the visitor's
>   device.

The project page for MT does say it's not ready for production though, which might be a problem - it depends when  it was last updated, as the last commit was this month.

***EDIT**

I COMPLETELY FORGOT ABOUT THESE!

[Browscap](http://drupal.org/project/browscap)

> Browscap provides an improved version of PHP's get_browser() function.

[Browscap block](http://drupal.org/project/browscap_block)

> Browscap Block adds visibility options to block configuration settings
>   to allow you hide or show blocks in mobile devices.

Browscap does depend on your server setup, but if you can use it then the second module gives you extra visibility settings for each block on the block edit page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use a jQuery cross browser support to get the screen resolution:

```
var browserWidth  = $(window).width();
var browserHeight = $(window).height();
```

Add simple PHP script to display setting of related block.

Comment: Thanks, but would that not mean converting the entire site to use AJAX for blocks? I'm looking to do this server-side if at all possible

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Mobile Detect Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_detect_block) but I'm currently looking for a solution that works with window width and either *`AdaptiveTheme`* or Breakpoints module media queries so as not to duplicate that code and weigh down the end-user download any more than it is. I also had mixed results with Mobile Detect not picking up on one device I tested it with, which makes it rather useless like Browscap if it can't provide reliable results.

Some discussions have some people wanting to get away from Browscap for one reason or another, hence the move to [Mobile Detect](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_detect_block).