# How can I return a different number of results per page for a view if a user is accessing the site with a mobile device?

Tags: views

I have a large number of views that show member profiles.  Right now, I only show 8 members per page, because on a mobile device it takes a very long time to scroll.

However, for the desktop, I could easily show 20 members per page.

Since there are a large number of views, I don't want to do this if I have to duplicate all of them and change the pager settings.  Is there another way to return a different number of results per page if the user is on a mobile device?

Comment: I just realised I asked [a very similar question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50850/managing-blocks-in-a-responsive-theme) a while back. If I remember rightly you're on Pantheon? I haven't found a sustainable way to do this yet with their enterprise package (to be fair to them I haven't gone down every possible avenue so it may well be possible)

Comment: Yes, good point-- I'm on Pantheon, so the solution has to work on Varnish too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would use something like [Views Infinite Scroll](https://drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll) instead of messing with the pager.  This would be better for most users in all cases.

However, you can use the [Mobile Detect](https://drupal.org/project/mobile_detect) module inside a [`hook_views_pre_build()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/7).  Something like this (untested)

```
function mymodule_views_pre_build (&$view) {
  $detect = mobile_detect_get_object();
  $is_mobile = $detect->isMobile();
  $is_tablet = $detect->isTablet();

  if ($is_mobile && !$is_tablet) {
    $view->pager["items_per_page"] = 8;
  }
  else {
    $view->pager["items_per_page"] = 20;
  }
}
```

This would affect all views.  `dpm()` the `$view` object to see how you would use it to add logic to limit to particular views and/or displays.

However, adding logic like this really complicates the cachability of pages using the normal methods.  The Mobile Detect module has a submodule that adds some ctools selection and access rules.  Using this, you could have view panes for device types, and then leverage Page Manager for caching.

*Disclosure: I am the author of the Mobile Detect module.*

Comment: I had originally avoided Views Infinite Scroll because it does not work with the iPhone and there is no consistently working patch (https://drupal.org/node/1180962).  However, I was able to get Views Load More (https://drupal.org/project/views_load_more) with Waypoints to provide infinite scroll instead.

Comment: @PatrickKenny The patched version of the jQuery plugin works for me.  Oddly enough, I have never gotten Views Load More + Waypoints to do infinite scrolling.

Comment: The current release of Views Load More requires a patch (https://drupal.org/node/1889300) for infinite scrolling to work.  Also, you have to turn on both "Use AJAX" (general views setting) and "Use infinite scrolling" (pager setting) in the options; this is not documented (I added a request for at least putting that info in the README, but who knows when it will be acted upon).

Comment: Would this work with boost enabled?

Comment: @nathan6137 Doubtful.  The module has some caching issues right now, similar to anything that modified behavior based on UA.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Browscap](https://drupal.org/project/browscap) module along with [Browscap Block](https://drupal.org/project/browscap_block) which would add the visibility of blocks depending on device. Next you could add two blocks one for Normal screen and one for mobile devices.

> **Browscap Block**
>
> Browscap Block adds visibility options to block configuration settings
>   to allow you hide or show blocks in mobile devices.

If you do not want to create multiple views then you could use the browscap function in your template file to detect the browser and then restrict the number of items displayed. The function would be `browscap_get_browser()`

This could either be done in `hook_views_pre_build` function or with in the `Style output` template file where it loops through the $rows array. you could restrict it the number to 8 depending on the device by exiting the loop once you reach the required count.

Comment: Without resorting to AJAX/ESI this is about the best you can get, although basing content on the UA string can be a bit hit and miss. You also need to give careful consideration to how you manage this, so you don't end up penalised in SERPs for showing different content to different users (your intentions are obviously harmless but there's no intuitive way for Google et al to know that), and so that all your content actually gets indexed. If your site's behind a reverse proxy it'll probably require some extra configuration on that server too

Comment: I am pretty sure it is too late in the template logic to alter view paging.

Answer (score 1):

For those that find this like i did, I am running drupal 10, look into [Responsive Views Pager](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_views_pager)
It is simple with all the settings in the pager part of the view.